# How can I feed an image into my neural network?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, computer-vision

So far I have trained my neural network is trained on the MNIST data set ([from this tutorial](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html)). Now, I want to test it by feeding my own images into it.

I've processed the image using OpenCV by making the dimensions 28x28 pixels, turning it into grayscale, and using adaptive thresholding. Where do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

An 'image' is a 28x28 array of values from 0-1... **so not really an image**. Just greyscaling your original image will not make it fit for input. You have to go through the following steps.

- Load your image into your programming langauge, with 784 rgb values representing pixels
- For each rgb value, take the average of `r`, `g` and `b`. Then divide this value by `255`. You will now have the greyscale of an image, a value between 0 and 1.
- Replace the rgb values with the greyscale values

You will now have an image which looks like this (see the right array):

[image]

So you must do everything through your programming language. If you just greyscale an image with a photoeditor, the pixels will still be `r,g,b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like PIL, skimage that let you load the data into numpy arrays in python and also support many image operations like grayscaling, scaling etc.

After you have processed the image and read the data into numpy array you can then feed this to your network.